# unexpected behavior when altering a list that I'm iterating through

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python and I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on here. Python is skipping every other number when using `for` to loop over a list, but only after a certain number of elements in. This is part of a larger project I'm working on, but this snippet of code illustrates it.

The code works properly until 7, at which point it begins skipping every other number. I know not to edit a list I'm in the process of iterating over, so I'm avoiding that, but the `for` isn't even calling some of them. What do I need to do to get it to loop through each number rather than every other? Why is it doing this?

Code:

```
import math

i1 = 60
l1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59]
l3 = l1

print(l1)
for a in l1:
    print(a)
    if a > math.floor(math.sqrt(i1)):
        print("REMOVED: " + str(a))
        l3.remove(a)

print(l3)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59]
2
3
5
7
11
REMOVED: 11
17
REMOVED: 17
23
REMOVED: 23
31
REMOVED: 31
41
REMOVED: 41
47
REMOVED: 47
53
REMOVED: 53
[2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 29, 37, 43, 49, 59]
```

Comment: +1 well presented question with all the detail needed to give you a clear answer (yay!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
l3 = l1
```

Now, `l3` and `l1` refer to the *same* list. Calling `remove()` on one will effect the other as well. So, when you call `l3.remove(a)` while iterating over `l1`, an item in `l1` (!) is removed, all the subsequent elements are shifted down, the loop iterates to the next element, and an item is consequently skipped.

For example, imagine that we're looping through the following list and we remove `b`:

```
-----------------
| a | b | c | d |
-----------------
      ^ (we're on b)

-----------------
| a |   | c | d |
-----------------
      ^ (remove b)

-------------
| a | c | d |
-------------
      ^ (shift elements down)

-------------
| a | c | d |
-------------
          ^ (step)
```

Notice that we skipped `c`.

Perhaps you meant

```
l3 = list(l1)  # create a new, independent list
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this is what I was thought it would do. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenH Glad I could help. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). By the way I also added a visual to help you better understand the skipping phenomenon.

Comment: @arshsajii Yes, I will accept it, just have to wait before stackoverflow will let me.... Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

`l3` and `l1` are pointing to the same list, if you want them to be unique, use `l3 = l1[:]`

Comment: really, the best way to do copying is `copy.deepcopy`. But since this is a list of ints, a simple shallow copy will do.

Comment: Even for a list of objects, `deepcopy` would be overkill in this case. (I was uncertain, so I tested it; if you think of lists as lists of references it is more obvious that altering the iterable of  the `for` is bad but that altering a shallow copy should not cause any issue).

Answer (score 1):

You don't remove elements from a collection while iterating it.  `l1` and `l3` are referencing the same list.  Perhaps what you intended is:

```
    l3= list(l1)
```

This will take a copy.